# Adding provisioning profile to new device on existing project

Tags: ios, xcode

I'm confused as to how to add a provisioning profile to a new device. So I'm using Xcode 4.3.2, and TestFlight. I was given a pre-existing project and a team license via the company I'm helping out. The provisioning profile on developer.apple.com had certain devices already set up. So I added all these devices as testers to TestFlight, sent out an archived build, no problems, worked fine.

Now, one of the testers wants to try out testing on an iPad. So, I sent them an invite via TestFlight, and their device automatically registered on TestFlight. I see their UDID, and device, etc. However, their device is listed under "Teammates Devices Not On This Profile". So, I followed the prompts, exported the missing UDID to a file, and uploaded the file to the Provisioning Portal. I see the iPad now under "Devices" in the Provisioning Portal, however it is listed with 0 profiles associated. How to I associate the provisioning portal of this app with the iPad? Is there some simple step I'm missing? Keep in mind this iPad is in a foreign location, so I have no control over it. I need to tell them what they need to do (or automate it myself). Please help!

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You need to add the device to the provisioning profile.  Then, build the project again using the updated provisioning profile.  And upload that build to test flight.

Or, I believe TestFlight has a new feature that allows you to simply update the build with the new profile without having to create a new build.

Comment: okay so how? Take TestFlight, for example. As stated above, I see the device and its registered, its just not associated with any profile. Where do I add it? If not TestFlight, then how else? Through the Apple Provisioning Portal site? I'm on there now but don't see how to. Or do I do it through Xcode?

Comment: So I went to the apple provisioning portal, downloaded a .cer file, then went to update profile on TestFlight. I chose the .cer file to upload, hit upload and boom 500 Error "Standby we're having Engine Trouble". So apparently I broke TestFlight. This is getting frustrating.

Comment: 1. Sign in to   https://developer.apple.com/devcenter/ios/index.action
2. go to the provisioning portal
3. Go to the provisioning menu
4. Go to distribution tab
5. Select your provisioning profile, and add the new device to it.
6. Download this provisioning profile            You may need the private key (this has to be provided by the person who generated the certificate)

Comment: Apparently there were a bunch of expired profiles associated with the app that were causing all the issues. Once I requested a new cert, and generated all the provisioning profiles from scratch, I finally got it to work. Was a bit more of a pain in the ass than I anticipated but this answer definitely got me going in the right direction.

Comment: 1. Sign in to developer.apple.com/devcenter/ios/index.action 2. go to the provisioning portal 3. Go to the provisioning menu 4. Go to distribution tab 5. Select your provisioning profile, and add the new device to it. 6.Go to your Xcode - Window - Organizer -> Provisioning Profiles (Hit Refresh the profile and certs will get updated with new device info) 7. Download the provisioning profile from developer website now and just update it on TestFlight it will update and show new device. Now you can run your app on new device :)

Comment: don't forget after adding a new device to go into Xcode -> preferences -> accounts, (if you are associated with multiple development teams, highlight the appropriate team) click, 'view details', hit refresh button.  This will replace your local provisioning profile with the new one that has the new device id's.

Comment: There is something missing from this solution.  When I add the devices to the profile and then download the newly edited distribution profile, and the double-click it to install it. Nothin seems to really happen. I see the new version of the distribution profile in the list of profiles in the organizer window, but when I build the app and upload the IPA, the devices still are not recognized. How do we ensure that the app gets built with the updated profile?